# PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE is 'ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible'

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I noticed following details in paypal response

```
'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => 'Eligible'
'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE' => 'ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible
```

I found details about these in [paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateAuthorization_API_Operation_SOAP/)

> **ProtectionEligibility:** the kind of seller protection in force for the transaction
>
> **ProtectionEligibilityType:** the kind of seller protection in force for the transaction

I can't understand what this really means. What should I do in my integration?

There is no any problem with checkout but I can't understand what should I do when receive these information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That info is simply provided so you know whether or not your transaction is covered by PayPal Seller Protection.  In this case it is eligible for potential disputes where the buyer claims they didn't receive the item or if a unauthorized payment was made (ie. stolen credit card, phished PayPal account, etc.)

You might get a transaction where it's Ineligible, or maybe still eligible but only for ItemNotReceived.  It all depends on the transaction and the variables involved.

So you don't really have to do anything when you receive that info other than decide how you want to treat the order.  If the item was Ineligible, for example, you may simply decide to cancel the order and refund the payment.